# Holder class of analytic functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Assume that $\lim_{(nt) |z|\to 1}|f(z)|(1-|z|)^p=0$, where $f$ is analytic in the unit disk and $p>0$,where $(nt)|z|\to 1$ nontangentially. Does this implies that  $\lim_{|z|\to 1}|f(z)|(1-|z|)^p=0$ uniformly?

Comment: Why the mysterious $nt$ and why is it the derivative? Are you asking if pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence in this case?

Comment: is it related to bloch space?

Comment: No, when I said $|z|\to 1$ uniformly  I had in mind that $z\to e^{it}$ for some $t$ and throughout the unit disk. Nontangentialy means that $z$ also tends to $e^{it}$ but inside an fixed angle.

Comment: &Koushik: It is related to little Bloch space.

Comment: So $(nt)$ just means "nontangential"?

Comment: Yes (n1) means nontangential!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not. There can be a region $D$ in the disc with one boundary point on the circle,
say $1$, which approaches this point tangentially. And a function which is bounded outside
$D$ but grows arbitrarily fast in $D$. To non-tangential limits of your expression at all points are zero, but there is no uniformity, and the growth is arbitrarily high.
Such function can be constructed in many ways, using for example approximation theorems,
or Cauchy integrals.